# View theme override in drupal 8

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I am new to drupal 8 and i need to override a views template. So, for that I have enabled theme debug in services.yml to view the twig template suggestion name.

This is my view theme debug.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_unformatted__test_content_view' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x views-view-unformatted--test-content-view.html.twig
   x views-view-unformatted--test-content-view.html.twig
   * views-view-unformatted.html.twig
-->
```

Then, I created the file in templates of drupal8 theme and the theme file calls. I used **themename_views_view_unformatted__test_content_view()** function to override in **themename.theme** file but the function doesn't called.

Is there anyway to override the variables coming to the twig template. Can anyone give me suggestion to override the views template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The template name is `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`, to override the variables in this template implement the preprocess hook for that template in your themename.theme file. E.g.

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  // Implement logic here to override the variables.
}
```

Comment: I did this but not working. The variables are empty when I printed inside the function.